# Show that a harmonic function has partial derivatives of all orders.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have a corollary in my textbook that says "If f(z) is analytic on a domain D, then f(z) is infinitely differentiable, and the successive complex derivatives f'(z), f''(z)...., are all analytic on D. I know I can use this corollary if I can show that u(z) has a harmonic conjugate, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Could be related to the Cauchy-Riemann equations... ;)

Comment: Do you know the Poisson integral formula?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a holomorphic function $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ is given by the partial derivatives of its real and imaginary parts: $f'(x+iy) = u_x(x,y) + i v_x(x,y)$. Now you can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to get what you are after.

Comment: That's not really an answer here because the OP doesn't know how to show that a harmonic function is the real part of an analytic function

Comment: I tried to be suggestive with my use of notation, but didn't want to give the answer away.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood. You are trying to give a hint on the conjugate business?

Comment: Yes, hence the mention of CR equations.

Answer (score 0):

any harmonic function is the real part of an analytic function , so we simply can find v(x,y) what is conjuctive in d , to u(x,y)
since v(x,y) is harmonic conjugate to u(x,y) , f(z)= u+ iv is analytic

hence , every analytic function it's derivates of all orders are analytic.